# Plain HTML or obfuscation from the start? How to test it with selenium?

Tags: html, obfuscation

I have an interesting problem. On one side I would like to "obfuscate" any page so that it is not possible to create robots, but on the other side I would like to test the same pages with a tool like selenium.

What would it be your current approach?

I found out that by using a tool like selenium I could even spot some "bugs" within the UI which passed some human driven tests. Namely the UI was working but apparently was not perfect.

One of the power of selenium is that you can test your web application as an "external" user. But on the other side it makes it fully "predictable" i.e. subject to web robots.

Comment: questions asking for opinions tend to get downvoted, however look at methods that bots would fall far but human wouldn't see such as honey traps

Comment: Actually, I was thinking more to a tool, like a compiler, not really an opinion. ;) like 2 versions of a web site: developers and a "compiled" or "obfuscated" one. If this could be one approach.